# Is it safe to pass in React component class instance to child component to access to the parent's variables and methods?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get data from parent component. I know that I can pass in functions or variables to the child component but its looks cleaner to just pass in `this` to child component to access to its parent functions or variables.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    _id: 123456789
  }

  foo = (val) => {
    this.setState({_id:val})
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Child parentInstance={this} />
    )
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  update = (e) => {
    this.props.parentInstance.foo(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <p>{this.props.parentInstance.state._id}</p>
      <input onChange={this.update} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: If you find yourself passing `this` down (as I did many times when learning React!), you’ll find it useful to re-read [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is more typical to pass properties and callbacks as props, not the instance itself.

i.e. `<Child parentId={this.state._id} onUpdate={this.foo} />`

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself passing `this` down (as I did many times when learning React!), you’ll find it useful to re-read [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html).

In this instance, you should be passing the ID down as a prop. When the state changes, React knows that it’s used to calculate that prop and so will re-render the child component.

As for the callback, that’s best handled as an individual function. If you find yourself passing many callbacks around in your app, you may want to look into using a more complex state management system than just Reacts internal `state` values.

```jsx
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    _id: 123456789
  }

  foo = (val) => {
    this.setState({ _id: val })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Child parentId={this.state._id} onChange={this.foo} />
    )
  }
}
```

```
class Child extends Component {
  update = (e) => {
    this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <p>{this.props.parentId}</p>
      <input onChange={this.update} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I had been passing methods and variables down individually to the child component but it often get messy when I have a lots of things to pass down... I guess that's what React suppose to be? Do you know any good way to pass down multiple things in simple way?? Thanks again.